# How to convert WP silverlight 8.1 project to WP 8.1 project?

Tags: win-universal-app

I had a WP 8 project which I wanted to convert to WP 8.1 so I can add a Windows 8.1 project to it to create a Universal App. But when I retargeted my project it was converted to WP Silverlight APP, so I can't find the "Add Windows 8.1 Project" option.

Any ideas how I retarget my project to be just WP 8.1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only Retarget `Silverlight 8.0` application to `Silverlight 8.1` application.

You **can't** retarget `Silverlight 8.0` to `Runtime 8.1` application.

But you can migrate your application. Here's the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229571.aspx) how you could achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a free tool that helps alot with the conversion. Check out this page http://www.mobilize.net/silverlight

if this link fails try googling Mobilize.NET Corporation and the file installer is named MobilizeNetSilverlightBridge.msi