# WindowsPhone Forms Project does not link with a PCL that does not target Windows Phone Silverlight 8

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

So, I have a core library that does not target Windows Phone Silverlight 8. When I try to add this project as a reference on my Windows Phone Project I got an error saying that this PCL is incompatible.  How I can configure my windows phone project to NOT support Silverlight ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't retarget the type of app (according to this post) but you can migrate. You might have to create a new universal / RT phone app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007802/1134836